# How can I change TelemetryChannel properties for Application Insights?

Tags: azure-application-insights

Microsoft provides documentation of many settings that can be set for the [TelemetryChannel class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.applicationinsights.channel.telemetrychannel.aspx) in Application Insights.

But I can't find any explanation of how these settings can be set.

Setting them in the ApplicationInsights.config file like this does not work for my web application:

```
<TelemetryChannel Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.ServerTelemetryChannel, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
  <DataUploadIntervalInSeconds>1</DataUploadIntervalInSeconds>
  <MaxTelemetryBufferCapacity>1</MaxTelemetryBufferCapacity>
</TelemetryChannel>
```

I simply cannot seem to influence my web app to honor these settings.

How can these settings be adjusted?

Answer (score 0):

The sample config in below git spark the idea of usage. You have to use Profiles & set these settings.

```
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">
 <ActiveProfile>Production</ActiveProfile>
<Profiles>
<Profile name="Production">
      <!-- <ServerAnalytics> controls Application Insights Telemetry SDK settings. -->
      <ServerAnalytics enabled="true">
        <!-- The frequency in seconds with which the SDK uploads data to Application Insights. -->
        <DataUploadIntervalInSeconds>60</DataUploadIntervalInSeconds>
</Profile>
  </Profiles>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

https://github.com/postsharp/ApplicationInsightsExample/blob/master/ApplicationInsightsExample/ApplicationInsights.config

Comment: Have you tried this and confirmed it works for you? I just tried this but it doesn't change the data upload interval for my app.

Comment: The config key got a new name: MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-sampling#adaptive-sampling-at-your-web-server

Comment: I just tried that setting and it still doesn't seem to work for the data upload interval. Are you sure this works for you?

Comment: Long back I worked with AI, currently I dont have access not possible to right now. will try once I have access..

Comment: If you want to quicken the data flush to AI from your end, you can try Developer mode (I dont know what they are calling it now)..